# A simplified rational exp, -n - 2, is not undefined at n=-2?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, rational-functions

A problem on Khan Academy asks you to simplify the equation

```
                     (1)   ((−3n^2+ 6n))/3n
```

(1) in its simplified form is

```
                      (2)   -n + 2.
```

Obviously at n = 0 in (1) the equation is undefined.

All of this makes sense to me so far, what is confusing me, however, is that the answer provided said:

**The only value of n for which (1) and (2) are undefined is 0.**

What is tripping me up is why (2) is not undefined at **both n=0 and n=-2.**

since,

for **n = -2**

**-n - 2**

=

**-(-2) - 2**

= **0**

In the other example problems **if a simplified rational expression had the form**

```
            (3)    x - 2
```

We would have considered the rational equation to have been undefined at

**x = 2**

since for,

**x - 2 = 0**

**x = 2**

Can someone explain why we consider **(3) undefined at x = 2,**

but not

**(2) at n = -2?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason a rational function may be undefined at a point is if that value makes the *denominator* zero. There is no problem, however, with having the *numerator* be zero (and the denominator be nonzero). Thus $-n+2$ is perfectly well-defined when $n=-2$, and it has a value of $0$ as you showed. Similarly, $x-2$ is defined when $x=2$ and has a value of $0$. Something like $\frac{1}{x-2}$ would *not* be defined at $x=2$ because you cannot divide by $0$.

Comment: Thanks, I see how -n + 2, and x - 2 are both defined when they have a variable that causes either equation to evaluate to 0, but when they evaluate to 0 does that mean that their parent rational function is undefined at the given value of that particular variable/

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "parent rational function." What I *think* you mean is a function $p(x)/q(x)$ which simplifies to, say, $x-2$, and even in that case the answer is no. The "parent rational function" $p(x)/q(x)$ is only undefined where $q(x)=0$. Where $x-2=0$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion here, as neither $(3)$ nor $(2)$ are undefined. That is, the rational function
$$ x - 2$$
is well-defined at $x = 2$. Indeed, as you have noticed, sticking in $2$ produces the number $0$. This is a perfectly reasonable number, and there is nothing odd about it at all.

Similarly, $-n + 2$ is perfectly well-behaved at $n = -2$. The number $0$ is just another number!

However, in the initial rational function
$$\frac{-3n^2 + 6n}{3n},$$
if you tried to plug in $0$ then you would get
$$ \frac{0}{0},$$
and what is that supposed to mean? That's why the initial rational function is undefined at $n = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. for (3), there were problems where (3) was the simplified rational expression and an independent variable that would cause (3) to evaluate to 0, would be said to cause its parent rational expression to be undefined even though ( 3) is. Idk, if that makes sense, lol, but is that a common occurrence?